# Can I create a dynamic AWS SNS filter policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We have clients that we want to subscribe to a `purchase_made` topic in our sns. However, they should only receive purchases that match their `clientId` (available as SNS event attribute).

Is it possible to have a dynamic [SNS filter policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html)? Something like:

```
messageAttribute.clientId == subscription.clientId
```

##### Background

I would like to avoid an explosion of topics when creating a dedicated topic for each client x event combination. (AWS quota: max 100k topics)

Since the AWS quota for filter policies is 200, it's not possible to create a filter polify per client.

Comment: This is probably not possible since the clientId is not someting visible / known to IAM. And neither do you have access to the filter policy within IAM. Even if a filter policy would work that would not suffice since a client could still receive other messages if they remove the filter policy. Or do *you* control the subscriptions and filter policies? You could flip this around and have a "dispatching service" that is subscribed to your topic, knows a mapping between clientId and targetTopic / targetQueue and forwards to those. The client could then manage their queue / topic themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The clientId is available in the filter policy as a MessageAttribute. So we can create a policy that only forwards messages for one specific clientId. The problem is that it does not seem possible to associate a subscription with a clientId and then link the two. :-/ Sorry my thread was a bit unclear: We control the subscription logic and filter policies; clientId is part of our application logic and does not directly relate to IAM entities.

Comment: I got that. So you do not really worry about the user being theoretically allowed to receive other messages - as long as the filter would be set up correctly, they would only receive specific ones, period, and they cannot change the subscription themselves, right!? I would probably suggest to go with the second approach and basically implement the filtering yourself - or contact AWS support if available in regards to the 200 subscription filter limit policy.

Comment: Good point, I will get in touch with AWS support. Otherwise, I might after all go with client specific topic names like `<eventName>_at_<clientId>`.

Comment: Is it not an option to let the customer create the topic, give you permission to publish to it and build the forwarding yourself? Should not be too much work but also not done in a couple of minutes.

Comment: The subscription process is done via our UI by non-technical people. So ideally, the customer does not need to do anything AWS specific on their side (besides inital setup once). But I will reflect a bit on your comment, maybe we are over-engineering.

Comment: Okay, not sure how many different events there are, whether each has a distinct topic, how many clients there are, etc. Difficult to suggest something that works in all cases. It is always "risky" to deploy infrastructure dynamically because you risk hitting AWS limits pretty quickly as you already see, it is always easier to distribute this across different accounts but this is certainly more complex.